# next button on keytoolbar setting last field as first responder,

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview, uitoolbar

i've got  two buttons on keyboard toolbar, the next button always sets the last field as my first responder, skipping all middle ones.. plus this keyboard toolbar is also not showing on that last field. ive got an array that store all the textfield and textview object and on click of next and prev  i use this array to determine which obj will become first responder 
 following is my code.

**this is where i create a keyboard tool bar**

```
-(void)createInputAccessoryView

 {
self.keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 44)];
self.keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.keyboardToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIButton *previousButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
[previousButton setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
[previousButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[previousButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoPrevTextfield) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

UIButton *nextButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
[nextButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoNextTextfield) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

//_btnPrev = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:previousButton];

//_btnNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nextButton];

_btnPrev =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoPrevTextfield)];
_btnNext=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoNextTextfield)];

 [self.keyboardToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_btnPrev,_btnNext,nil] animated:NO];}
```

**this is where i create an array of objects**

```
-(void)addTextFieldObjectsToArray
 {
textFieldsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:22];

[textFieldsArray addObject:companyNameFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:contactPersonFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:customerPhoneFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:customerEmailFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:distributorNameFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:distributorSalespersonFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:distributorPhoneFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:distributorEmailFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:closetStandardFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:cylinderVelocityFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:cycleRateFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:operatingPressureFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:cylinderMountFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:wieghtOfRodAttachmentFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:rodAttachmentFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:sideAttchementFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:environmentConsiderationFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:ambientTempFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:quantityFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:competitorFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:currentApplicationIssuesFieldObj];
[textFieldsArray addObject:modificationRequiredTextViewObj];}
```

**now here are my next and prev button code**

```
-(void)gotoPrevTextfield{
for(int i=1 ;i<22;i++)
{

        if([textFieldsArray [i] isFirstResponder])
        {
            [textFieldsArray[i-1] becomeFirstResponder];
            [textFieldsArray [i] resignFirstResponder];

            break;
        }

}}

 -(void)gotoNextTextfield
 {
   NSLog(@"%s","inside next Field");

for( int i=0 ;i<21;i++)
{
    if([textFieldsArray [i] isFirstResponder])
    {
        [textFieldsArray [i+1] becomeFirstResponder];
        [textFieldsArray [i] resignFirstResponder];

        break;
    }

}}
```

now at time when my any textfiels is clicked i use *didbeginediting* function for both textfield and textview..
**here are my func code**

```
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     _txtActiveField = textField;
     [self.txtActiveField setInputAccessoryView:self.keyboardToolbar];
  }}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{


    if ([textView isFirstResponder]) {

        _txtActiveView =textView;

        [self.txtActiveView setInputAccessoryView:self.keyboardToolbar];

    }}
```

the very last object is textview, others are text fields. please help me understand why  my all fields are being skiped and my last field is being set as first responder on next button click

Comment: you can use  BSKeyboardcontrol which is very good for your requirement .

Comment: also my keyboard toolbar is not showing when the control reaches to textview did begin editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice for your requirement is [BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls) .

Please have a look

https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls#installation

https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls#usage

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is wrong. Coz of the for loop, The final result of      **-(void)gotoNextTextfield** would be that **[textFieldsArray[21] becomeFirstResponder]**. and obviouslyit wil skip other fields and your last field would be set as first responder when u click next button.

Comment: @sho-Z .. just put the break point outside.. and it worked.. :P